# How to lock a thread based on thread ID?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 3 classes,and which has been shared by 3 threads. Each thread going to access a common list which is synchronized. But the problem is, I just want to lock a thread based on ID and un-lock the next one If the previous is completed.

**Example**

I have thread-1, thread-2, thread-3 which is going to access a list simultaneously. I need to lock thread-2 and thread-3 based on its' id until thread-1 complete. And let them executed one by one.

I'm using JAVA programming to achieve this. Please help me to find a way to achieve this.

Comment: so there wouldn't be a problem if Thread-1 and Thread-2 would access the list simultaneously? What programming language btw?

Comment: No. I want to lock other threads and execute only one based on It's id. once the current thread completes, then it has to unlock next one, and let it execute. It needs to happen when multi thread interacts with specific list.

Comment: if you synchronize on the list it should actually do what you want, threads will access this code-block only after another thread has completed the execution

Comment: Yes. its happening but the problem is, it's not maintaining order. Ideally I want to perform some write action by using the list. that's the reason I just want to lock a thread based on ID's. If the thread is completed based on ID, then I could see the order of data in list. followed by remaining thread will maintain the order in list.

Comment: hmm, how about you use `ExecutorService` - class and submit your Write-Tasks to it? The tasks will keep their order. Just make sure your Executor uses only 1 Thread

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Let me try this.

Comment: If you expect threads to do something in a particular order, you should not use multiple threads. Threads run *concurrently* which is even farther away from being ordered than just being unordered…

Comment: Re: "I need to lock t2 and t3 based on its' id until t1 complete. And let them executed one by one."  Why do the IDs matter?  A simple `synchronized` block will insure that the threads can only execute its content "one-by-one."

Comment: Actually the scenario is that t1,t2,t3 threads will interact with list 'n' number of times. example: t2 call a list 5 times and same time t1 call a list 3, and t3 is 4 times. If all these threads interact only once then synchronized is the way to achieve. But, some tasks could be done by multi thread but I need to lock them when It call a list. Because the list of data going to be written in a file for some reference, and It should be in order.

Comment: @arrchanaMohan You could use `notify`/`wait`. A thread loops on `wait` until it is its turn to go. A thread calls `notify` any time it changes which thread should go next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be done by ExecutorService.invokeAll() method. My primary objective is keep the order o/p.

Please check the below URL:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

I hope it may help someone. thank you all. This issue can be closed.